# how to set device ('cuda', 'cpu') for pyro PyroModule

Tags: pytorch, pyro.ai

I'm trying to learn a bit about pyro and building probabilistic neural networks with pytorch.  Normally, with a pytorch.nn.Module I can move it to the GPU with `model.to( 'cuda')` however this does not seem to work with a pyro Module.  How does one correctly place a pyro Module model onto the GPU?

Example Model:

```
import torch
import pyro
import pyro.distributions as dist
from pyro.nn import PyroModule, PyroSample
import torch.nn as nn
from pyro.infer.autoguide import AutoDiagonalNormal
from pyro.infer import SVI, Trace_ELBO, Predictive

class Model(PyroModule):
    def __init__(self, h1=20, h2=20):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = PyroModule[nn.Linear](1, h1)
        self.fc1.weight = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([h1, 1]).to_event(2))
        self.fc1.bias = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([h1]).to_event(1))
        self.fc2 = PyroModule[nn.Linear](h1, h2)
        self.fc2.weight = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([h2, h1]).to_event(2))
        self.fc2.bias = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([h2]).to_event(1))
        self.fc3 = PyroModule[nn.Linear](h2, 1)
        self.fc3.weight = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([1, h2]).to_event(2))
        self.fc3.bias = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([1]).to_event(1))
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x, y=None):
        x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
        mu = self.fc3(x).squeeze()
        sigma = pyro.sample("sigma", dist.Uniform(0., 1.))
        with pyro.plate("data", x.shape[0]):
            obs = pyro.sample("obs", dist.Normal(mu, sigma), obs=y)
        return mu
```

then:
`model = Model()`
however `model.to( 'cuda')` does not seem to actually move the model to the GPU.

---

Update: I'm not sure if this is a correct solution...
I find that if I replace `PyroSample` with `pyro.nn.PyroParam` then they are listed in the ParamDict and can be moved to the gpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into a similar problem. Even though `PyroModule` is subclassed from `nn.Module`, as far as I can tell, the `.to` method does not work to carry over `PyroSample` objects the same way one might expect for `nn.Parameter` objects. (I think it might work for `PyroParam`, like you say).

I found [this](https://forum.pyro.ai/t/pyrosample-and-cuda-gpu/4328) Pyro forum post to have a workable solution. It says you can initialize the `PyroSample(dist...)` calls with tensors that are already on the GPU. For example, change lines like your

```
self.fc1.weight = PyroSample(dist.Normal(0., 1.).expand([h1, 1]).to_event(2))
```

to

```
self.fc1.weight = PyroSample(dist.Normal(torch.tensor(0., device="cuda"), 1.).expand([h1, 1]).to_event(2))
```

I've found this is only a problem when you have multivariate `PyroSample` objects (i.e., you have the `.expand..to_event..` here). If it's a univariate object then the variable transfers from the CPU to GPU without complaining.

Comment: This does, in fact, seem to work.  However I'm not sure how to then transfer back to 'cpu' after training.  It seems that after initialization there's no clean way to transfer back and forth between devices.

Comment: I thought I might be able to save the pyro parameters with: `pyro.get_param_store().save( file_path)` and then reload them with: `pyro.get_param_store().load( file_path, map_location='cpu')` but it still fails when creating a predictive model for use.

Comment: The `PyroSample` variables aren't parameters that will be stored in `param_store`. Depending on what kind of inference algorithm you use, the posteriors can be stored in a few different ways. If using MCMC, you can get the samples as tensors and transfer those to CPU if needed. If using SVI, you can save the parameters of the *guide* using param store after a long training loop. Then you can reload them in another process using `param_store = pyro.get_param_store()

param_store.load("param_store")`. 
More info here: https://pyro.ai/examples/bayesian_regression_ii.html